# Simple JavaScript Swap function

Tags: javascript, image, swap

I'm having difficulty in correcting the syntax error for image swap. I would appreciate if you can help me out as below?

```
function swap(i, s)
{
   var d = document.images;
   d ? d[i].src=s : null;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use the [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
function swap(i, s) {
    var d = document.images;
    if (i >= 0 && i < d.length) {
        d[i].src = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, Evin.

Comment: I made a slight mistake so I edited the question and fixed it, @Irishgirl